# Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request

Tags: security, web-development

I have a joomla website installed and working good. i installed Qlue404 component which redirects 404 page to a custom page., sometimes when i try the symbols ' and some others the 404 page appears with the message "Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."
also it shows the server information
*Apache mod_fcgid/2.3.6 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 Server at mywebsite.com Port 80*

how can i disable this message? i swear this leads to get all information for a hacker to do an Sql Injection.

Comment: It does not allow "to get all information for a hacker to do an Sql Injection."

Answer (score 1):

From [Apache's docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/custom-error.html):

> Use of [ErrorDocument](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#errordocument) is enabled for .htaccess files when the
> [AllowOverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#allowoverride) is set accordingly.
>
> Here are some examples...
>
> ErrorDocument 500 /cgi-bin/crash-recover
> ErrorDocument 500 "Sorry,
> our script crashed. Oh dear"
> ErrorDocument 500 `http://xxx/`
>
> ErrorDocument 404 /Lame_excuses/not_found.html
> ErrorDocument 401 /Subscription/how_to_subscribe.html
>
> The syntax is,
>
> ErrorDocument <3-digit-code>  where the action can be,
>
> - Text to be displayed. Prefix the text with a quote ("). Whatever follows the quote is displayed. Note: the (") prefix isn't displayed.
> - An external URL to redirect to.
> - A local URL to redirect to.

Basically what you want to do is place this snippet in a .htaccess file in your root web directory to contain this (obviously you will want to change the URL to one you prefer):

```
ErrorDocument 404 /my-custom-404-page.html
```